# Xcode 12.5 - How to enlarge editor font?

Tags: xcode

I am mildly visually impaired and find the default font size hard to read if the code I'm looking at is "crowded."

I've searched "Preferences" multiple times and found nothing. Please help. I'd even settle for a back door like editing a plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the *code* font size? It's in the preferences under Themes, and can also be changed on the fly in the menus under Editor -> Font Size.

(However, there's a lot of other very tiny text scattered all over the interface, and the only way to make it less tiny is to zoom the whole screen or otherwise adjust the screen resolution.)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. You don't have to be visually impaired to recognize the tremendous importance of reading code comfortably. Between the various themes and the other customization options in the Themes pref pane, I'm sure you can find something that works for you. It also helps to have a Retina monitor and to be willing to make various adjustments to the screen in general.